# How to open a new window in the same page

Tags: javascript, window

I have a button:

```
<button>Click</button>
```

I want click it and open a new window in the same page, I bind the click event an event handle:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var newurl="http://" + window.location["host"] + ";
    window.open(newurl, '_parent');
})
```

But is always open in new tab or new window, the second parameter I have try `_self` `_top`.
I even have try `window.location.href(newurl)`

So how can I solve this problem?Does it matter with browser or OS? I view it in Mac OS's firefox and chrome.

Comment: What you ask is impossible. "New window" is mutually exclusive with "same page." It sounds like you really just want to change the URL in the current window/tab.

Comment: Do you wish to open the url in the current window? I am not sure whether or not I understand your question right.

Comment: @EricG: Yes, you understand is right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well that's not possible technically, it also depends on browser tab settings, window settings and third party tab manipulation plugins or addons.

---

## Update

**OP has cleared the confusion of all** through his comment below his question, this is what you need to set a new url for current window:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var newurl="http://" + window.location["host"];
    window.location.href = newurl; // or simply window.location
})
```

Comment: @Christoph: It reloads a new url in **same** window not **new** window

Comment: @Christoph: Agreed, his comment below his question clarifies now

Answer (score 1):

`window.location =newurl;` will open a new window replacing the parent

Comment: It will not open in **new** widnow, the actual question

Comment: the question is not phrased well I assume

Comment: it will change the url inside same window, it won't open new one

Comment: If you read it carefully there is "But is always open in new tab or new window", so he obviously doesn't want it to open in a new window, he just wants a new page opened in the current window.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.open ('test.htm','_self',false)
</script>
```

Comment: Read the question? " I have try `_self`"

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to replace the current page, `window.location = newLocation;` will do.
If you want a modal popup, try JQuery UI Dialog.