# Open a window on the same Site

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

sorry for my English…

[how to show the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVLO1.png)

hi, I to want when someone clicks the zoom icon it opens a small window in the Site, I`ll this small window describe a product.

HTML code how to build this image,

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

         <div class="col"> 

          <div class="product-grid">

                <div class="product-image">
                   <a class="link" href="/tachen_&_rucksacke/fenster/mochila_doble_tirantes-violeta.php">
                    <img alt=""  class="bild" src="photo/111.jpg">     
                   </a> 

                </div>

                <div class="product-content">
                     <a class="links" href="/tachen_&_rucksacke/fenster/mochila_doble_tirantes-violeta.php">
                    <p class="title">Mochila doble tirantes Violeta</p>
                    </a>     

                </div>
                    <div class="price">$16.00</div>

                     <div class="div-zoom">

                   <span class="zum-warenkorb">zum warenkorb hinzufügen</span>
                   <i class="fa fa-search-plus" style="font-size: 94%; color: white; background-color:  #595959; padding: 3%;"></i>
                 </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Css code where add to basket (**zum warenkorb hinzufügen** of german language..) and click to zoom icon

```
/*  div-zoom-fenster   */

.div-zoom { padding: 2%; padding-top: 15%; text-align: left;}

/*  zum-warenkorb    */
.zum-warenkorb { font-size: 89%; background-color: #bfbfbf; color: #ffffff; padding: 2%; margin-top: 2%; text-align: left;}

.div-zoom i {padding-bottom: 5%; margin-left: 4%; }
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11243212/12999026) someone says that it is possible with **JQuery**, but I don't know about **JQuery**..

Can please someone help me, Thanks!

Comment: are you using bootstrap? if yes, which version?

Comment: Very Thanks for your answer!, yes bootstrap 4

Comment: You can use the modal boostrap, they are popin opened by clicking somewhere, usually on a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay here is what you need to do. Although I have created an example for you, but read these steps:

1. You need to call jQuery CDN and Bootstrap JS CDN,
2. you need to create a modal given in bootstrap official documentation on getbootstrap.com

   3. Use the MOdal as it is as given there and just call ts trigger on your zoom button as I did for you, Go ahead and click on zoom button.
   4. Put your modal content in the modal body, whatever you want, Images, divs, text.

```css
/*  div-zoom-fenster   */

.div-zoom { padding: 2%; padding-top: 15%; text-align: left;}

/*  zum-warenkorb    */
.zum-warenkorb { font-size: 89%; background-color: #bfbfbf; color: #ffffff; padding: 2%; margin-top: 2%; text-align: left;}

.div-zoom i {padding-bottom: 5%; margin-left: 4%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

         <div class="col"> 

          <div class="product-grid">

                <div class="product-image">
                   <a class="link" href="/tachen_&_rucksacke/fenster/mochila_doble_tirantes-violeta.php">
                    <img alt=""  class="bild" src="photo/111.jpg">     
                   </a> 

                </div>

                <div class="product-content">
                     <a class="links" href="/tachen_&_rucksacke/fenster/mochila_doble_tirantes-violeta.php">
                    <p class="title">Mochila doble tirantes Violeta</p>
                    </a>     

                </div>
                    <div class="price">$16.00</div>

                     <div class="div-zoom">

                   <span class="zum-warenkorb">zum warenkorb hinzufügen</span>
                   <i class="fa fa-search-plus" style="font-size: 94%; color: white; background-color:  #595959; padding: 3%;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#zoomWindow"></i>
                 </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="zoomWindow" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      
        <button type="button" class="close text-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      <div class="modal-body">
        put here, whaterver you want
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry I had your answer later to show, it is for me the best answer because I don't know anything about jQuery and your answer is easy to implement on my code. I wish you a nice day!

Comment: I'll your upvote but have only  13 points...minimum muss has 15 points...

Comment: @jdgs56z, now you can upvote :D